# How to load geometry point tables in sql spatial

Tags: sql-server, spatial

Need help loading point data in sql spatial.

Similar to this post but I really dont know how to get XY data to be accessible by sql

I want to do what was done in the initial part of this post (Identify points that plot inside the polygon):

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166399/how-do-i-find-points-that-are-not-within-a-list-of-polygons-using-ms-sql

```
SELECT points.name, polygons.name
    FROM points CROSS JOIN
    polygons
    WHERE  (polygons.shape.STContains(points.shape) = 1)
```

How do you get the points loaded into your table and sql to recognize the points with out having to define them like the below?

```
insert into @points values 
(geometry::Point(1,1,0)), 
(geometry::Point(2,3,0)), 
(geometry::Point(5,4,0)), 
(geometry::Point(4,2,0))
```

I am having a hard time defining points without doing it manually like above

Ideally I could build a table like this by selecting the xy data I have in a table already

Answer (score 1):

Its very clunky but you need to use stpointfromtext

```
geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(xxxxx yyyyyy)', SRID)
```

...where `xxxxx` andf `yyyyy` are the coordinate values and `SRID` is the grid identifier for the projection you are using. Wrap it all up with a cursor like in the following example:

[Insert geometry from XY coordinates using SQL](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012317) (ESRI | Technical Support)